# There is a problem with Mysql grouping the maximum row value

Tags: java, mysql, group-by

Mysql version 5.7
In group query, each group takes the maximum value, but the values of other columns are not the values of the row with the maximum value

```
    select d.userid,f.accesstype,MAX(f.createtime) from  tb_project a
    inner join tb_contractor b on b.projectId=a.projectId
    inner join tb_team c on c.corpBusinessId=b.corpBusinessId
    inner join tb_user d on d.teamBusinessId=c.teamBusinessId
    inner join tb_personauth e on e.userid=d.userid
    inner join tb_accessrecords f on f.personguid=e.personguid
    where a.projectId =  '7AA5537B25D94DF5A6EF347B785D70F6' and
    DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) <= date(f.createtime)
    GROUP BY d.userid
            ORDER BY d.userid desc
```

[image]

```
select f.* from  tb_project a
        inner join tb_contractor b on b.projectId=a.projectId
        inner join tb_team c on c.corpBusinessId=b.corpBusinessId
        inner join tb_user d on d.teamBusinessId=c.teamBusinessId
        inner join tb_personauth e on e.userid=d.userid
        inner join tb_accessrecords f on f.personguid=e.personguid
        where a.projectId =  '7AA5537B25D94DF5A6EF347B785D70F6' and
       to_days(f.createtime) = to_days(now())
and d.userid='fd5a48caf2544cd5803e7933bd09a96f'
order by f.createtime desc
```

[image]

Can only subqueries be used？
Different functions, different query results
why？

[image]

[image]

Comment: *Can only subqueries be used?* Depends on precise MySQL version. On 8+ window function FIRST_VALUE() will solve.

Comment: *Mysql version 5.7* - subquery anycase.

Comment: `to_days(f.createtime) = to_days(now())` causes fullscan anycase. Use `f.createtime >=CURRENT_DATE AND f.createtime < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY`, this form is sargable.